# Running multiple stories in sequence

Tags: selenium, sequence, jbehave, user-stories

I have multiple stories under a package. Can someone give me the runner code for executing all the jbehave story files in a sequence.

I have been using the storyPaths method but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

well, if you need to execute them in sequence the easier way is to rename your stories to add a sequence number at the beginning of its name. something like: "0_my_first_story"

Answer (score 0):

`storyPaths()` simply returns a `List<String>`. You can get the file `List` yourself and sort it using Java.

Alternatively, you could leverage the [`GivenStories`](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html) as a pseudo dependency management. If you need story Z to run before story X, have X specify GivenStories Z. I haven't done this myself, but it seems like it might work. More info [here](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/given-stories.html).

Finally, just renaming them alphabetically is always an option.